# how to get audio automatically in python ( wait till the users speaks)?

Tags: python, automation, speech-recognition, pyaudio

There is two type of mic input (push-to-talk and automatic). Push-to-talk is basically calling the function but i dont know how to implement it automatic, that is if there is a audio noise recognized or wait till the user speaks, then audio will processed to text.Also all this have to happen in real-time .
( if there are better ways please teach me )

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

def audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Speak Anything :")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print("You said : {}", format(text))
        
        except:
            print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")


while True:
    audio()
```

Now this function works when i call it once, and the time it took to generate the exception is 8 seconds (waiting time till to talk) but when the function is called in the loop it generates exceptions for every 8~10 sec but the problem is if i talk something it doesnot recognise in the middle ( i feel inefficient as it fails sometimes, it does not wait till user speaks )

are there any other efficeint ways?

Comment: Please add more context to your question. What library is it that you are using. If I want to try your example I will get `sr is not defined`.
What are you looking for a more efficient solution with this specific library? Are you looking for a a more efficient general solution? etc.

Comment: i have included the package, speech_recognition as sr

Comment: so if I try to install speech_recogntion with `pip install speech_recognition`, pip does not find anything. Could you try to include just enough information so people can help you :)
If I do a search on pypi.org for `speech recognition` I get 3664 results. See the problem ?

Comment: pip install SpeechRecognition is the package, link for the package info is https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/